# how does return statement work in a void function?

Tags: c++

This function works fine in a program. But can I get the explanation of the work of return statement in preorder function... if statement?

```
struct myNode{
    int data;
    myNode *prev, *next;
};

void preOrder(myNode *node) {
    if (node == NULL) 
        return;

    cout << node->data << " ";
    preOrder(node->prev);
    preOrder(node->next);
}
```

Comment: it just "cancels" the function. It's a so called "precondition". If this condition is met, it will simply not execute the function.

Comment: It returns from the function stopping execution at that point.

Comment: If `node` is a null pointer (i.e. it points to no object) control is returned to the caller of the function.   Otherwise, the following three statements are executed (resulting in, in your case, infinite recursion).

Answer (score 4):

If the function returns `void`, `return` still governs control flow.

In this case, if `node` is `NULL`, the function exits immediately, and subsequent code in the function is not executed. By doing so, this particular function ensures that the `data` member cannot be accessed on a null pointer. This is a common pattern you will see in many functions.

***Nitpick***: as this is C++ rather than C, `nullptr` would be more idiomatic than `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

`return` means the execution of the function will stop at this line and below lines of code will not be executed. Since below we have `node->data` and we don't want to access `data` of `node` if `node` is null so we wrote `return` command there.

Comment: If `node` is null, we also wouldn't want to evaluate `node->prev` or `node->next` - let alone pass either to a recursive call of our function.

Answer (score 1):

Void is a valid return result just like anything else. The only difference is there is no object being returned (simply return nothing).

In general whatever the return type of a function, the return statement causes the function to exit, which will cause the return value to be copied (or moved) to the destination location of the call and all local objects (currently initialized) to be destructed. The only difference between void and any other type that copying or moving a non object is very cheap.

```
void myFunc1()
{
    if (condition) {
        return;   // return nothing (same as void).
    }

    // Do Stuff;

    // Don't need an explicit return for void.
    // But you can have one if you want.
    return;
}
```

You can also return the result of a void call from another void function.

```
void myFunc2()
{
    return myFunc1();   // If myFunc1 returns a void.
                        // and this function returns a void.
                        // you have a valid return.
}
```

I know it does not seem useful. But when you start playing with templates and the return type is not always obvious, it is useful to know that `void` behaves exactly like other types being returned from a function (except there is no void object itself so is very cheap to construct :-) ).